# Can't get Certbot SSL for domain running on AWS ec2 container

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm trying to run my AWS ec2 instance on an https server. I'm trying to get an SSL certificate using Certbot. When I try running the certbot command I get the following error

```
$  sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d {domainName}.com -d www.{domainName}.com -v
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Requesting a certificate for {domainName}.com and www.{domainName}.com
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for {domainName}.com
http-01 challenge for www.{domainName}.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain {domainName}.com
Challenge failed for domain www.{domainName}.com
http-01 challenge for {domainName}.com
http-01 challenge for www.{domainName}.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: {domainName}.com
  Type:   connection
  Detail: 3.134.161.84: Fetching http://{domainName}.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/vbKXVQypnPDXQeo_ILFwxRxtVP5tWg0vnkWGLVjqsLg: Connection refused

  Domain: www.{domainName}.com
  Type:   connection
  Detail: 3.134.161.84: Fetching http://www.{domainName}.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/oX4IYyOCaC38aUdbtousy2ODiomST4_grl1FaLAA5ng: Connection refused

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.

Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

- Here are my security groups for the instance:
  [image]
- Here are my DNS records:
  [image]
- Here is my Nodejs backend code...if that matters:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//--------------------HTTPS--------------------*/

 try {
  const cred = {
    key: process.env.HTTPS_KEY,
    cert: process.env.HTTPS_CERT
  };

  const httpsServer = https.createServer(cred, app);

   httpsServer.listen(process.env.PORT_HTTPS, () => {
     console.log(`listening to localhost: ${port}`);
   });
  } catch(err){
    console.log('HTTPS err:', err.stack);
  }

app.listen(process.env.PORT_HTTP, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`listening to port:${process.env.PORT_HTTP}...`);
})
```

- env

```
#PORTS
PORT_HTTP = 3000
PORT_HTTPS = 8443
```

- npm script

```
npm run server

> portfolio@1.0.0 server
> nodemon server/server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server/server.js`
HTTPS err: Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at node:internal/tls/secure-context:69:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at setCerts (node:internal/tls/secure-context:67:3)
    at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:156:5)
    at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:121:3)
    at Server.setSecureContext (node:_tls_wrap:1353:27)
    at Server (node:_tls_wrap:1212:8)
    at new Server (node:https:73:3)
    at Object.createServer (node:https:109:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/portfolio/server/server.js:47:29)
listening to port:3000...
connected to postgres database: portfolio
```

I've redirected inbound requests to certain ports knowing that I don't have access to them

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

I've looked at the logfile and it says nothing to me

```
$ sudo head /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
2023-07-28 13:43:14,680:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:None "GET /v2/connections?snap=certbot&interface=content HTTP/1.1" 200 97
2023-07-28 13:43:14,923:DEBUG:certbot._internal.main:certbot version: 2.6.0
2023-07-28 13:43:14,923:DEBUG:certbot._internal.main:Location of certbot entry point: /snap/certbot/3024/bin/certbot
2023-07-28 13:43:14,923:DEBUG:certbot._internal.main:Arguments: ['--standalone', '-d', '{domainName}.com', '-d', 'www.{domainName}.com', '--debug-challenge', '--preconfigured-renewal']
2023-07-28 13:43:14,923:DEBUG:certbot._internal.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#apache,PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#nginx,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#standalone,PluginEntryPoint#webroot)
2023-07-28 13:43:14,936:DEBUG:certbot._internal.log:Root logging level set at 30
2023-07-28 13:43:14,937:DEBUG:certbot._internal.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator standalone and installer None
2023-07-28 13:43:14,939:DEBUG:certbot._internal.plugins.selection:Single candidate plugin: * standalone
Description: Runs an HTTP server locally which serves the necessary validation files under the /.well-known/acme-challenge/ request path. Suitable if there is no HTTP server already running. HTTP challenge only (wildcards not supported).
Interfaces: Authenticator, Plugin
```

POSSIBLE ISSUES

- 1 DNS error: Unlikely as it's pointing to the public IP listed in my ec2 instance and I've tested it

```
$ dig {domainName}.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> {domainName}.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42317
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;{domainName}.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
{domainName}.com.   300 IN  A   3.134.161.84

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 28 14:45:28 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 66
```

- I also tested the `www` version of the address

```
$ dig www.{domainName}.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> www.{domainName}.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53485
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.{domainName}.com.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.{domainName}.com. 300   IN  CNAME   {domainName}.com.
{domainName}.com.   300 IN  A   3.134.161.84

;; Query time: 60 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 29 19:11:48 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84
```

-2 Firewall: I don't think it's that either considering how my inbound rules are configure

-3 user authorization: I'm running the sudo command, which should give me the same access at the root user

Does anyone have any suggestions?

- UPDATE:
  I've flushed the DNS cache on my container because I thought it might be outdated...error still persists

```
$ sudo resolvectl flush-cache
```

- UPDATE:
  I've noticed that when my server is running on my Ec2 the error message type changes from `connection` to `unauthorized`

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: {domainName}.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 3.134.161.84: Invalid response from http://{domainName}.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/77bznoympb2FlZDIU8XJqHG4c-Q58qqfCTOX93bNThI: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"

  Domain: www.{domainName}.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 3.134.161.84: Invalid response from http://www.{domainName}.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/cY_cv8nGaLqgjHMRF8PvhtAUSD-sNf6mM9XP4RQcl1o: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.

Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

I think this might have to do with my CSP

```
  //------CSP
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const nonce = crypto.randomUUID();
    const csp = `default-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://'*'.letsencrypt.org/ 'nonce-${nonce}' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/ http://fonts.gstatic.com; img-src 'self' https://res.cloudinary.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com https://maps.googleapis.com data: w3.org/svg/2000; font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/ http://fonts.gstatic.com; base-uri 'self';`;
    res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', csp);
    return next();
  });
```

I've tried granting permission for scripts from `https://'*'.letsencrypt.org/`
but that hasn't worked either